# System.Data.DataRowView' does not contain a property with the name error when click link button

Tags: c#, asp.net

[whork on run](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ApW7q.png)

when I clicked it give me this error 'System.Web.HttpException: 'DataBinding: 'System.Data.DataRowView' does not contain a property with the name 'catId'.'

code to load data to list view

```
string categoryQuery = "SELECT COUNT(b.catId) as noOfBlogByCategory, b.catId as catId, c.categoryName 
                        FROM category c 
                        JOIN blog b ON c.categoryId = b.catId 
                        GROUP BY c.categoryName, b.catId";
DataTable tableCat = da.dataFromQuery(categoryQuery);
noOfCategoryByBlog.DataSource = tableCat;
noOfCategoryByBlog.DataBind();
```

my list view code

```
<asp:ListView ID="noOfCategoryByBlog" runat="server">
  <ItemTemplate>
    <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" 
      runat="server"
      class="list-group-item list-group-item-action"
      onClick="btnCategorizedBlog_Click" 
      CommandArgument='<%#Eval("catId") %>' >
      <%#Eval("categoryName") %>
      <span class="badge badge-secondary"><%#Eval("noOfBlogByCategory") %>
    </asp:LinkButton>
  </ItemTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
```

Link button click code

```
protected void btnCategorizedBlog_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    LinkButton btn = (LinkButton)(sender);
    int categoryId = Convert.ToInt32(btn.CommandArgument);
    string categoryQuery = " SELECT blogId,blogHeader, blogImg, blogIntro FROM blog WHERE catId = '" + categoryId + "' ";
    DataTable tableCat = da.dataFromQuery(categoryQuery);
    noOfCategoryByBlog.DataSource = tableCat;
    noOfCategoryByBlog.DataBind();
    blogByCategory();
}
```

Comment: The categoryQuery in btnCategorizedBlog_Click should probably select catId as well, right?

Comment: thank u, sir, I found my mistake. i add to the different list view. because of your comment, I realize that i am adding to the category view.